# Getting the latest row from status

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Supposed I have a table with the following rows

| test_no | test_count_no | test_status | test_run_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | STOP | 1 |
| 2 | 66 | FINISH | 1 |
| 3 | 67 | FINISH | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | STOP | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | STOP | 2 |

I need to get the row which has a `test_status` of `FINISH` and has the latest `test_no`,

for example `test_run_no=1` since there is `two test_status` of `FINISH`, I only need to get the latest `test_no` which is **3**

In case of `test_run_no=2` since there is no `test_status=FINISH` i only need to return the first row.

The result will be:

| test_no | test_count_no | test_status | test_run_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 67 | FINISH | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | STOP | 2 |

My current query is

```
SELECT MAX(test_table.test_run_no)
FROM test_table
WHERE test_table.run_status = 'FINISH'
GROUP BY test_table.test_no
```

Any idea on what query should I add in order to achieve the result ?

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: im sorry im using mariadb and the version is 10.4.14

Comment: @Beginner Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery fits this:

```
select t.*
from test_table t
where t.test_no = (select t2.test_no
                   from test_table t2
                   where t2.test_run_no = t.test_run_no
                   order by (test_status = 'FINISH') desc,
                            (case when test_status = 'FINISH' then test_no end) desc,
                            test_no asc
                  );
```

The `order by` has three keys for your conditions:

- Put `'FINISH'` first.
- For `'FINISH'` get the largest `test_no`.
- For others, get the smallest.

This logic can also be expressed using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by test_run_no
                                order by (test_status = 'FINISH') desc,
                                         (case when test_status = 'FINISH' then test_no end) desc,
                                         test_no asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from test_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following statement:

```
select * from test t where t.test_status = 'FINISH'
and t.test_no = (select max(t1.test_no) from test t1
                 where t1.test_run_no = t.test_run_no)
union
select * from test t where t.test_status = 'STOP'
and not exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.test_run_no = t.test_run_no
                and t2.test_status = 'FINISH')
and t.test_no = (select min(test_no) from test t1
                 where t1.test_run_no = t.test_run_no);
```

It consists of two `SELECT` parts. In the first part, for the tests that have a `FINISH` status, the one with the highest test number is selected.
The second part selects the smallest test number for the tests for which there is no run with the status `FINISH`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
SELECT MAX(test_table.test_run_no) FROM test_table 
where test_table.run_status = 'FINISH' and test_run_no=1 
GROUP BY test_table.test_no
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  select MAX(test_table.test_run_no) from test_table GROUP BY test_table.test_no
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use order by desc and use limit 1 to get the exact row.
Like this

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE test_table.test_status = 'FINISH'
ORDER BY test_no desc
LIMIT 1
```

if you need all the rows

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE test_table.test_status = 'FINISH'
ORDER BY test_no desc
```

if you need test_no only

```
SELECT test_table.test_no
FROM test_table
WHERE test_table.test_status = 'FINISH'
ORDER BY test_no desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it will just get 1 row

Comment: @Beginner that's what you requested in question !!! "I only need to get the latest test_no which is 3" if you need all the rows just remove the 'LIMIT 1'

Comment: @Beginner did you get the solution ? Is this answer not right ?

Comment: sorry thats not what i'm looking for

Comment: @Beginner then ? please explain, i can provide you the answer

Comment: @Beginner : see this was your question - "for example test_run_no=1 since there is two test_status of FINISH, I only need to get the latest test_no which is 3" isn't my last query working correctly for you ?

Comment: I also need to get the other row even if it is not status=FINISH look the question at last part the result should be like that

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
select * from Table_3 where Table_3.test_count_no = (
select max(test_count_no) from Table_3
) and Table_3.test_status = 'FINISH' and Table_3.test_run_no = 1
union all
select x.test_no, x.test_count_no, x.test_status, x.test_run_no from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Table_3.test_run_no) as rownum, Table_3.* from Table_3 where Table_3.test_run_no = 2) as x where x.rownum = 1
```